# @font-face not loading in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, font-face

I have included some .ttf fonts in a child-theme in Wordpress. I have two separate dev environments too, which are identical. In one, the fonts load just fine, however in another the fonts will not load at all. I look at the errors in inspect element and see:

GET http://thedomain.com/wp-content/themes/theme-child/fonts/Alice-Regular.ttf 
It doesn't even say "404" failed to load, and furthermore states that this line of code is on the index page, when it is in fact in a style.css file in the child theme.

For all of my non-google fonts, this is what happens on them...but only on ONE environment. The paths are 100% correct, and I have put a "/" in front of the path, and took it off, I did absolute paths, and virtually all musical chairs I could possibly do with the path.

I've cleared cache, cache-busted, and all of that, but the fonts just do not load.

This is the CSS (WHICH WORKS ON MY FIRST ENVIRONMENT), and YES, the 'fonts' folder is in the same directory as the style.css
I even took the fonts out of the folder and placed them in the same directory as the style.css and adjusted the path in CSS accordingly - no go.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Bazar';
src: url('fonts/Bazar.ttf');
font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'Cuban';
src: url('fonts/Cuban.otf');
font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'Alice-Regular';
src: url('fonts/Alice-Regular.ttf');
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Have you add your custom font in the `functions.php` with `wp_enqueue_style` like for example: `wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-font', "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans");`?

Comment: check permissions on the uploaded font files

Comment: I didnt do that on my first environment and it's working fine there.
These are font files too btw, not google fonts (perhaps that was just in your example, if so - my bad). And furthermore all of my google fonts are working fine too.

Comment: Font permissions are all the same from environment to environment. 0705 on the folder and 0604 on the font files themselves.

Comment: Have you tried this `./fonts/font_name.ttf` ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:

```
Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts there (and so on...)
To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep moving forward
```

Using @font-face
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: I appreciate this, but I'm well aware of this. The paths are the exact same paths in two environments that are identical (one for testing, one for dev) at this moment. It isn't the file path.